# Laravel route returns 404 (Laravel 6.6.2)

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have multiple routes where every route works except one. I keep getting a 404 page even though I cleared the cache and also checked the list of the routes with

```
php artisan route:list

| GET|HEAD| team/requests/{$teamId} | team_requests | App\Http\Controllers\TeamController@requests                           | web                          |
```

The route appeared on the list.

My route looks like this

```
Route::get('team/requests/{$teamId}', 'TeamController@requests')->name('team_requests');
```

My controller action looks like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TeamController extends Controller
{

    public function requests(int $teamId)
    {
        $requests = User_Team::where('team_id', $teamId)->where('isInvitation', false)->get();
        $userRequests = [];
        foreach ($requests as $request) {
            $userRequests[] = User::find($request->user_id);
        }

        return view('requests')->with('requests', $userRequests);
    }
}
```

I'm running the website currently with the laravel localhost server using:

```
php artisan serve
```

I think I must have a typo somewhere but I can't find anything. Does someone also had this issue?

I'm using Laravel 6.6.2

Comment: you don't use a `$` in the definition of a route parameter, its just `{teamId}`, btw

Comment: Thank you very much! I've been wasting so much time on this. It fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the solution from lagbox.

The problem was that I was using $ in the defintion of the route parameter.
Removing it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

While declaring parameters in the route.php, no need to declare with '$'. Just simply, write by {id} or {teamid}, rest I think is OK.

Here is a [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#required-parameters) on how to add parameters to the URL in routes.

Also, I think, you should upgrade to Laravel 8, there are some cool features in it.

Though, you already got your solutions, hope this too helps. Thank You :)